# Fiddler not seeing requests

Tags: http, proxy, fiddler

Have just installed fiddler for analyzing http traffic and performed the following configuration.

1. Capturing is on
2. Filter all processes is on
3. Unchecked hide Images, CONNECTS, and 304 under rules
4. Checked Automatically Authenticate under rules
5. Fiddler listens port is 8888 under Fiddler Options -> Connections
6. Use System proxy under Fiddler Options -> Gateway is checked
7. Current Gateway info under Fiddler Options -> Gateway shows my companys proxy config script http://wtd.ten.thomsonreuters.com/proxy.pac

IE browser has automatic configuration script of http://wtd.ten.thomsonreuters.com/proxy.pac under LAN settings set

When accessing a an external web page via any browser no information is being captured in fiddler.

However if i enter 127.0.0.1:8888 in any browser then fiddler captures this request, which suggests to me fiddler is not able to see any normal URL requests due to mis configuration.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click Fiddler's `Log` tab just after startup. Does it mention anything about your proxy settings being controlled by group policy?
2. Click `Help` > `Troubleshoot Filters`. What do you see?
3. When Fiddler is capturing, what do you see inside Tools > WinINET Options > LAN Settings?

Comment: The Log tab after startup only mentions fiddler is running, and contains no other information.

Comment: Troubleshoot filters displays the fiddler echo service which displays some information about request e.g troubleshooter.cgi and response 200, along with originating process info e.g. iexplore: 20924. The Alternate hostname test on the page fails, get a network error of type dns_unresolved_hostname, but this looks like it is generated by the company network. there are 3 of these messages, one each for ipv4.fiddler, ipv6.fiddler, and localhost.fiddler.

Comment: LAN settings opened from fiddler tools -> wininet options shows use automatic configuration script is checked with address http://wtd.ten.thomsonreuters.com/proxy.pac
Use a proxy server for your LAN is not checked and bypass proxy server is checked and grayed out